# Colour profiles in Gnome Color Manager

Tags: 11.04, color-management

I'm trying to change contrast/brightness on my monitor, thus I downloaded Gnome Color Manager. It says there is no color profile for my monitor. Then I inserted the monitor's driver CD and imported some color profiles from it. However, Gnome Color Manager told me that the profiles I imported are missing information for whole-screen color correction. I tried searching the web for colour profiles with not much luck.

On Windows I could easily change the brightness/contrast using the ATI Catalyst Control Center. What can I do with this on Natty? Is there another option? The OSD options of my monitor don't do what I want, they work awkwardly. Measuring color with an expensive device is out of question.

The monitor is a Xerox XA3-17.

Answer (score 1):

I use the proprietary ATI driver on Natty. It comes with a Catalyst Control Center that allows me to control brightness, contrast etc.

If you have an ATI graphics card the driver should be easy to install if you go to 'Additional Drivers' in Ubuntu.

I don't know how to adjust contrast etc. without using the closed-source driver though.